# JS shorten for array creation with object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, simplify

How can i shorten this code?

```
const allChartContextActionsData = [];

allChartContextActionsData.push({
  data: {
    channelKey: this.props.getSocket().id
  }
});

return allChartContextActionsData;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an array and pushing an object to it, you could just return a new array with the object in it straight away:

```
return [{ data: { channelKey: this.props.getSocket().id } }];
```